# when i trying to drag and drop image in nicEdit redirect that same link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, nicedit

I am using nicEdit for user who can add code in editor but when image drag & drop in this box that will redirect the page to perticular url. This error accured in only chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

nicEdit apparently does not support image drag & drop by default.
Check here: http://nicedit.com/demos.php

Here's an alternative that claims to be the first WYSIWYG editor WITH image drag & drop support: https://imperavi.com/redactor/

Comment: But this functionlity working in mozila firefox so it is not working in chrome browser?

Comment: Not here. I've tested the original demos in Chrome on Mac (El Capitan) and they don't support drop at all, Chrome simply displays the image file in the browser instead of the demo site, after dropping said image onto the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: sorry friend but my quetion is it is working in mozila but why not working in chrome. my client has found that error